# check if NSDate object exist in NSArray of NSDate objects

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, nsdate

I have NSArray of NSDate objects but I want to know if there is a way to check if I already have a NSDate object in the NSArray such as:

```
if ([myArrayOfDates containsObject:thisDate])
```

where thisDate is a nsdate object with a date.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: `if ([myArrayOfDates containsObject:thisDate])` what happened when you use that code ?

Comment: So are you looking for an EXACT match, or only something "close enough"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are little things which if you try by yourself, makes you better and inspires you to try it on your own every next time. You see, I didn't know the answer myself, so I created a small test code to see if different date objects with same date can be compared using [NSDate equal:] method and here is my code,

```
NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray array];

NSDateComponents *yesterdayDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
yesterdayDateComponents.day = -1;


NSDate *yesterdayDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:yesterdayDateComponents
                                                                      toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                     options:0];
NSLog(@"%@", yesterdayDate);

[dates addObject:yesterdayDate];

NSDate *newYesterDayDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:yesterdayDateComponents
                                                                         toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                        options:0];

if ([dates containsObject:newYesterDayDate]) {
    NSLog(@"Date are same");
}
```

Try it on your own and see.